# how to query metricbeat system cpu and memory data stored in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How can I get number of cpu utilization in a particular environment in elasticsearch query

I have tried with this query, but its returning entire response object

```
GET metricsindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "metricset.name":"cpu"
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "host.name":"example.locall"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, you only want certain fields and not all the fields, to be returned in the response? Could you also post the JSON response in the question? Question is quite unclear.

Comment: And you you want to get the individual documents or an aggregation? "number of cpu utilization" sounds like an aggregation to me, right?